# Firefox Only: FB.login() called before FB.init()

Tags: facebook, firefox, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Using the Facebook SDK, I get the following console error when trying to connect a user to my site. The "Connect with Facebook" button works fine in all other browsers, except Firefox.

I have a Channel URL in the innit config, and I've confirmed this issue happens in Firefox installs without Firebug. The following is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
     appId :  'my_real_app_id',
     channelUrl : 'MYURL.com/channel.php',
     status:  true,
     cookie:  true,
     xfbml :  false
  });
};

(function(d) {
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a#login-fb').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
           console.log('Welcome! Fetching your information...');
           FB.api('/me', function(response) {
              handleFacebookLogin(response);
           });
        } else {
           console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize');
        }
     }, {scope: 'email, offline_access, user_birthday, publish_stream, publish_actions' });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you come up with a fix or a workaround for your issue? If so, it'd be nice if you could push it in as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this issue by changing my above javascript, right below #fb-root to the following:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({
        appId :  'my_id',
        status:  true,
        cookie:  true,
        xfbml :  false
     });
  };

  (function() {
     var e = document.createElement('script');
     e.async = true;
     e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
     document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());

  //rest of code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue in a Rails project and it helped to bring the

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId:my_real_app_id, 
        cookie:true,
        status:true, 
        xfbml:true
    });
```

out of header and have it in the `<script>` tag just below the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` in body.

Answer (score 0):

For the browser platform, the plugin seems to be using the post prepare plugin to populate the `APP_ID`.  It assumes this is specified in `config.xml` in the root of the project. I am not sure why - but this was missing in my config generating the error.

Adding this line to `config.xml`, seems to resolve the problems

```
<preference name="APP_ID" value="0123456789"/>
```

Note: the implementation seems to be based on an inline replacement of the special token `APP_ID` in several files (see `plugins/cordova-plugin-facebook4/scripts/after_prepare.js`).

In my situation this had been set to null (presumably the first time it ran without the above entry in `config.xml`). To resolve this I reinstalled the plugin and browser platform.

```
$ ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-facebook4
$ ionic cordova platform remove browser
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save --variable APP_ID="0123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApp"
$ ionic cordova platform add browser
```